# How to remove directory in Windows synchronous

Tags: winapi

`RemoveDirectory()` is documented as only marking a directory for deletion. I have an application where I have to be sure that the directory is actually deleted (because I create a new one with the same name, or delete directories recursively).

First idea I had was to use `GetFileAttributes()` to test if the directory still exists, or to use `SHFileOperation()` for deletion. But when running long test, at some point both solutions fail - `CreateDirectory()` fails.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps you can rename the directory first (to a random name) and then mark it for deletion. It will eventually be deleted. You can then always create the directory with the original name.

Comment: You'll get an "access denied" error when you try to do anything with the directory.  That's how you know.  Solution, well, no.  It isn't fundamentally different from trying to overwrite a file and that file is already in use by another process.  Which you have to solve by finding that process or waiting until it is done.  It is the self-inflicted causes that tend to be hard to diagnose.  Like anti-malware or having your program's current working directory set to that same directory.

Comment: Who says that "only marks the directory for deletion"? In MSDN is written "The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed." This means that the directory will not be deleted if it is in use. But if "last handle to dir" is closed, it will be deleted - maybe immediately? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809788/impossible-to-remove-directory?rq=1

Comment: @i486, "immediately" possibly, but that's still not necessarily _synchronously_.  Various security software can insert themselves into the delete process, causing the delete to take longer.

Answer (score 2):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhRWMGBjlO8) by Douglas Niall at the 2015 CppCon covers the solution in detail, starting at about 7:30.

The idea is to first rename (move) the file or directory to another place (on the same volume), which happens synchronously, and then delete it, which happens asynchronously.

Consider this tree:

```
C:\Users\me\
  foo\
    bar\
      obsolete.txt
```

If you try to remove `bar` after deleting `obsolete.txt`, it may fail because there can be a delay before `obsolete.txt` is *really* deleted.

Instead suppose you first move `obsolete.txt` to `C:\Users\me`, and give it a temporary name to ensure it doesn't collide with another `obsolete.txt` in the directory.  Maybe you prefix it with a GUID, like `2DCD7863-456C-4B6C-AD84-C4F5E8009D81_obsolete.txt`.  Now you can delete the file using that temporary name, and, even if there's a delay before it's really deleted, you know `bar` is truly empty.  You can now delete `bar` or create a new `obsolete.txt` in `bar` without worries of a conflict.

To remove `bar` (a directory) on the way to deleting `foo` (the root of the tree you're trying to delete), you play the same game.  Move it to the parent of the root, call `RemoveDirectory`, and then proceed along your merry way knowing that it will eventually be deleted.

Comment: I believe this does not work with directories. It's not always true that I have the right to write to the parent directory. So I cannot move it there. Second, I also cannot move it to %TEMP% because %TEMP% can be on a different drive and `MoveFile` can not move directories across drives.

Comment: @RobertK, if you have the right to delete `foo`, then don't you necessarily have the right to write to `foo`s parent?  I suppose you could run into a quota problem if not everything in the hierarchy is charged against the same owner, but that seems extremely unlikely.  (It's true that `%TEMP` can be on a different drive, and that's a problem.)

Answer (score -1):

Possible options:

- Delete Directory and check for its existence afterwards
  if no handle was open, it is deleted. if a handle is still open there is another problem. Optionally you can wait a few ms after each existence check until it disappears.
- Delete all files inside the directory
  you mentioned you want to recreate it, so just delete its content. Doing this allows you to see which files/folders are still open inside the directory.

Comment: `RemoveDirectory()` fails if the directory is not already empty.

Comment: As said even if the check for existence succeeds (=directory does not exists anymore) creation of a directory with the same name can fail.